# C# how to get a list of open "TcpListeners"

Tags: c#, networking

I want to add multiplayersupport to one of my games, so i created a "Create Server" button which opens a TcpListener and listens to connecting requests, and a "Join Server" button, I want this button to display a List of all open TcpListeners (so the user can click on them an connect)
are there any in-built functions for this in c#?

Answer (score 3):

You want a list of all listeners, on all machines on the network (or the entire internet)? Then the answer is no, there's no built-in function for that.

On a small LAN, you might be able to get away with the servers broadcasting their presence. This is how games usually did it before the internet came along.

Nowadays, they usually connect to a central server, which has a list of all servers that are hosting the actual games.

Either way, you'll have some work to do.

Comment: sry I was not precise enough, its for lan usage only

Comment: In that case, have the clients listen on a UDP port, and have the server broadcast its presence on that port. The clients then know they can connect back to the server on the address that the UDP packet came from. And you can put some data in the packet, such as the server name, game type, player count...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this functionality for this in the IP or TCP Spec.  Neither IP nor TCP provide any "service locater" type of functionality.

To implement this functionality, you need some way for your players running the servers to broadcast their connection information (ip address / port number) to the other players looking for a game.  This is traditionally done through having a host / co-ordination server that publishes the information for the available games.

Answer (score 0):

If you're limiting to a local area network you could broadcast on the port your game servers are listening on and have them reply with some kind of registration message.

To keep it from interfering with the game you could even separate it and have a separate registration service that listens on a different port than your game listens on.